# Error "'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed " when using pd.get_dummies on test dataset

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create dummy variables for my test data set inorder to make test and train dataset of the same dimension

I am trying to solve House prediction problem on Kaggle

```
dataset = pd.concat(objs=[df_train,df_test],axis=0)
dataset_pre = pd.get_dummies(dataset)
df_train = dataset_pre[:train_objs_num]
df_test = dataset_pre[train_objs_num:]
```

It is showing

```
'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `kaggle` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Can you run `dataset.info()`? Are you sure all columns in `dataset` can be one-hot encoded?